# Rails button_to not routing to specified controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following

```
<%= button_to(t 'submit', {:controller => "transactions", :action => "confirm", :p => product.id, :locale => params[:locale] })%>
```

was running in rails version 3.2.18 but after updating to 3.2.21 the generated code routes to the page it was generated on (itself), which is wrong.  The params have also been dropped from the rendered HTML.

Did not expect a syntactic change over a minor release... then again the above syntax may be somehow flaky and generated in the past by some form of serendipity.

Answer (score 0):

Very subtle

```
<%= button_to(t('submit'), {:controller => "transactions", :action => "confirm", :p => product.id, :locale => params[:locale] })%>
```

the translation string required parenthesis for i18n handling.